# How to set name of Android app Bundle in Android Studio?

Tags: android, bundle

How do I set the name of Android App Bundle (aap) in Android Studio, when I build the bundle?

It always generates an AAP named bundle.aap.

Comment: This is not yet configurable. You can add a gradle task to rename the output if you desire. Note: it's AAB, not AAP :)

Comment: Do you have an example how to rename the bundle? I'm having different problem, I was using the variant.assemble.doLast hook to copy proguard mapping, but when I'm generating bundle it calls bundleVariant instead of assembleVariant :-/